# What are all the references in "Black Museum" to other episodes?

Tags: black-mirror

In the Black Museum, there are a number of artifacts straight from other episodes of *Black Mirror*. On top of that, there's visual or audio references.

Some obvious ones are:

- Arkangel tablet
- Tub from Crocodile
- Reference to San Junipero, uploading old people to the cloud
- Cookies, something from White Christmas
- A mannequin dressed as a shotgun wielding person from White Bear

I've read about a few more, but haven't seen a good, concise list of everything people have spotted. (Visual aides and actual dialogue a bonus).

Answer (score 6):

It was a fun episode. I noticed several items as well and had a similar question. Per the Wikipedia site the "Black Museum" includes Easter egg references back to each previous Black Mirror episode, according to director Colm McCarthy; many were placed by set designer Joel Collins [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Museum_(Black_Mirror)):

Additionally, beyond Black Museum there are Easter Eggs throughout season 4 including several listed [here](http://www.nme.com/blogs/tv-blogs/black-mirror-season-4-easter-eggs-2204418).

For Black Museum specifically:

1. The hanged man

   Carlton Bloom, from the first episode of Black Mirror, hanged himself. An exhibit of the incident is shown in Rolo’s museum.
2. ’15m Merits’

   Season 1’s Fifteen Million Merits episode is referred to by a graphic novel titled ’15m Merits’.
3. Victoria Skillane

   There’s a video of season 2’s White Bear protagonist in the museum, and we also see the ski-mask man from that episode.
4. Kenny & Hector

   The museum’s curator, Rolo Haynes, has two white lab rats called Kenny & Hector – named after the two blackmailed protagonists of Shut Up And Dance.
5. PM Callow

   The Prime Minister from season 1’s The National Anthem is referenced on a tablet screen in this episode, where a seemingly serious newsreel reads: “PM Callow marries pig”.
6. San Junipero

   There are several references to this beloved season 3 episode. Rolo Haynes worked for TCKR, the company that developed the San Junipero project. It appears the project was named after the Saint Juniper hospital where Haynes had worked previously. And dresses worn by Yorkie and Kelly are shown in the museum.
7. The robotic bee

   One of Hated in the Nation‘s bees are on display too.
8. Tommy’s lollipop

   This USS Callister artefact is displayed alongside that episode’s Raiman’s Milk, and Daly’s DNA scanner.
9. Bloody bathtub

   This object, the location of a Crocodile murder, is part of the exhibition.
10. Arkangel tablet

    The smashed tablet from Arkangel is in the museum.
11. Harlech Shadow

    The deadly game from Playtest can also be seen.
12. Be Right Back

    The name of the charging station in this episode, ‘BRB Connect’, is a reference to the season 2 episode Be Right Back.

Finally, separately, one wall of the museum includes a number of human face
busts; Brooker identified these as busts of the various crew that
have worked on the show.