# What are the references to Alice in Wonderland?

Tags: alice-in-wonderland, alice-in-borderland

In the series *Alice in Borderland*, there are logically several references to the book *Alice in Wonderland*.  Most notably, the protagonist goes by Arisu (Alice) and finds himself in a bizarre world where he is subject to arbitrary and incomprehensible rules involving playing cards. The main plot is pretty distinct, though, involving lethal games that they are forced to play (seemingly) by some sadistic entity with effectively complete control over their lives.

Besides the obvious plot reference, are there any other references to *Alice in Wonderland* or *Through the Looking-Glass*?

Comment: There are quite a [number](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178990/what-are-all-the-references-in-black-museum-to-other-episodes) [of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198671/what-are-the-references-of-the-company-names-in-orconomics) [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237939/what-references-to-the-man-from-u-n-c-l-e-are-present-in-randall-garretts-t) that ask "What are the references in (this thing)?", so I am going to disagree that it needs focus.

Comment: I've voted to close because the question is basically a self-answer. As such it lacks focus.

Comment: @Valorum - I am certain that there are *far* more references, and I could certainly remove that portion.  I just did not want the "You idiot, the title/main character is an obvious reference" downvotes.

Comment: I have the same objections to this that I have to questions by certain other users. Once you've cherry-picked the obvious examples, what you're left with is always going to be a series of short (and probably largely opinion-based) *'I found one too!'* answers.

Comment: @Valorum - Not if some smart cookie can find all of them first. I am sure any big Lewis Carroll fan who has watched the show and knows more Japanese than I do could do it.

Comment: My Japanese is not strong. About on a par with my Latin and worse than my French.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of other name references:

1. Usagi means rabbit. The White Rabbit is the first character who leads Alice through Wonderland, and Usagi is someone who takes charge of Arisu and helps him through Borderland for a while.
2. Chishiya comes from Cheshire. Like the Cheshire cat, Chishiya is enigmatic, always smiling, and it's not entirely clear whose side he's on.
3. There's a character named Hatter in both, and both run a neverending party.

Spoilers for the manga:

> 4. An important character, and the last main "villain" that Arisu faces is the Queen of Hearts.

> 5. Arisu plays croquet with the Queen of Hearts.

> 6. At the end Arisu "wakes up"--and it was all a dream, or similar to a dream.